# Data binding - access individual properties contained in LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

Is there a way to do something like this with LiveData and data binding?

ViewModel has this property:

```
val weather: LiveData<UnitSpecificCurrentWeatherEntry>
```

What I'm trying to do in the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@{viewmodel.weather.value.someProperty}"... />
```

Is this possible in any way or do I have to split the object contained in LiveData into multiple ones for each property of the contained object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the point of view of MVVM pattern it's not entirely correct. In your example view require know about *property path* to display data. Preferable to provide target data directly from `ViewModel`. If your property is depend from another, you can use `Transformations`:

```
val weather: LiveData<UnitSpecificCurrentWeatherEntry> = //suppose, we have instantiation here
val someProperty: LiveData<SomePropertyType> = Transformations.map(weather) { it.someProperty }
```

Now, you can use it in your xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@{viewmodel.someProperty}"/>
```