# Data binding with LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-livedata

I am new to Architecture components and Data binding I am trying to update my Textview field in layout once i get response from API. Now my final response is in a Livedata like this:

```
  public class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(var mApplication: Application, var repository: LoginRepository) :
ViewModel() {


var username: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>()
var password: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>()
var finalSet: MediatorLiveData<WeatherData> = MediatorLiveData()

init {
    username.value = ""
    password.value = ""
    finalSet.addSource(repository.dataList) { it ->

        finalSet.postValue(it)
    }
}

    fun getWeatherData(): MediatorLiveData<WeatherData> {




        return finalSet
    }
```

and this is my layout file

```
    <data>

    <variable
        name="loginViewModel"
        type="check.test.com.myapplication.login.LoginViewModel" />
    />


</data>
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{loginViewModel.}" />
```

This is my data class

```
      class WeatherData {


@SerializedName("coord")
var coord: Coord? = null
@SerializedName("sys")
var sys: Sys? = null
@SerializedName("weather")
var weather = ArrayList<Weather>()
@SerializedName("main")
var main: Main? = null
@SerializedName("wind")
var wind: Wind? = null
@SerializedName("rain")
var rain: Rain? = null
@SerializedName("clouds")
var clouds: Clouds? = null
@SerializedName("dt")
var dt: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int = 0
@SerializedName("name")
var name: String? = null
@SerializedName("cod")
var cod: Float = 0.toFloat()
  }

  class Weather {
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int = 0
@SerializedName("main")
var main: String? = null
@SerializedName("description")
var description: String? = null
@SerializedName("icon")
var icon: String? = null
 }

class Clouds {
@SerializedName("all")
var all: Float = 0.toFloat()
  }

  class Rain {
@SerializedName("3h")
var h3: Float = 0.toFloat()
 }

  class Wind {
@SerializedName("speed")
var speed: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("deg")
var deg: Float = 0.toFloat()
}

class Main {
@SerializedName("temp")
var temp: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("humidity")
var humidity: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("pressure")
var pressure: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("temp_min")
var temp_min: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("temp_max")
var temp_max: Float = 0.toFloat()
 }

 class Sys {
@SerializedName("country")
var country: String? = null
@SerializedName("sunrise")
var sunrise: Long = 0
@SerializedName("sunset")
var sunset: Long = 0
 }

 class Coord {
@SerializedName("lon")
var lon: Float = 0.toFloat()
@SerializedName("lat")
var lat: Float = 0.toFloat()
 }
```

Now what i want is that once i have the data in finalSet variable the Textview text should be updated.

I thought of doing it this way:

```
         <data>

    <variable
        name="loginViewModel"
        type="check.test.com.myapplication.login.LoginViewModel" />
    />

    <variable
        name="data"
        type="check.test.com.myapplication.login.WeatherData" />
    />


</data>
```

and giving value to data element in Activity observer like this

```
    viewModel.getWeatherData().observe(this, Observer { data ->


        binding.data = data

       // startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))


    })
```

I am aware of using observable fields and do this. I am also aware that this can also be done if i pass this property to a new variable and assign it in layout file but i want to understand the best practice to do this.

I have tried following many blogs and few questions available here but none of them is helping with the best way of doing this.

Requesting everyone here to enlighten the path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is the [binding adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it many ways.
You can transform your livedata to your required data type:
In your viewmodel:
    val newData=Transformations.map(finalSet){it.model.data}

Here you are getting your finalset and getting the partiicular data from your finalSet data which contains a model object

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{loginViewModel.newData}" />
```

It will be trigerred when your finalSet has a valid data

Comment: As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746799/data-binding-access-individual-properties-contained-in-livedata this is not the best way of doing this.

Comment: Also my LiveData is not of a data type it is further a Model.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check and tell me if you have any doubts @HarrySharma

Comment: This is the same answer mentioned in the link mentioned by me :)

Comment: It is one way of doing. Different people do the same things differently

Comment: I know bro. Just checking the best way of doing it :)

Comment: Check googles code samples in their github repository. Pretty sure that would be the best way you can find